# Is it possible to project an image onto water?

Tags: optics, visible-light, water

Is there a way to create an image/projection in the water? Or form the water to project an image, little dot/pixel? Use some type of frequency to modulate the little dot in the fluid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comment on user1512321's answer it seem that your question is whether it is possible to project an image inside water. I do not know whether you mean a 2D or 3D image, but after a quick search on the internet I found [this article](http://www.popsci.com/technology/article/2011-11/3-d-projection-tech-makes-images-hover-mid-air-no-screen-necessary), which uses focused laser beam in to generate plasma excitation in atoms of oxygen and nitrogen in the air, but in the video they also state that it also works underwater.
In the demonstration they only used one color at roughly 10-15 fps, but the article is from 2011, so I assume there must have been some developments with this technique.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want to project an image onto a liquid surface?

Sure, it's possible but it's not "easy". Whenever there is a change of index of refraction (n), there will be some light that "bounces", a reflection. Any optics text book should have these equations. These equations depend on the angle, polarization, and change in n between medium 1 and 2.

The equations are reproduced here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations

Note that there are two equations, one for parallel to the plane, the other for perpendicular to the plane.

However, reflecting the light is only half the story. You still have to make sure that the light system properly "images" the picture, i.e. it's focused. That's require some geometric optics work.

Also, you still have a signal/noise problem. The reflected light will probably not be very significant, and ambient light will overwhelm it (That's why you can only see reflection on a glass at night). Also, unless you're projecting onto a deep pool of water, you'll get reflections from the container's surfaces as well.

Finally, unless your water surface is perfectly calm it'll be almost impossible to create a focused image. In this case you should still be able to image onto the surface by sampling the surface shape and calculating the inverse of it's optical effects and correcting for it. But, that's hard!

Comment: the fluid would be in a closed box and under light pressure. So the image will need to be projected not on the surface but inside the fluid.

Comment: why does it "need" to be projected inside the liquid? If you're trying to achieve a 3D effect, you can look into holograms. Also there are techniques to make things appear as if they're projected within the solid. But light will continue going along a straight line unless it encounters a change in n, or a scattering point

Comment: imagine black box filled with water. I need to be able to create a pixel in the liquid(water). Let's say there is a camera connected and records the pixels.